# Statsmodels seasonal_decompose - what is naive about it?

Tags: python, r, time-series, statsmodels

Have been working with time series in Python, and using `sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose`. In the [docs](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/release/version0.6.html?highlight=seasonal#seasonal-decomposition) they introduce the function like this:

> We added a naive seasonal decomposition tool in the same vein as R’s `decompose`.

Here is a copy of the code from the docs and its output:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

dta = sm.datasets.co2.load_pandas().data
# deal with missing values. see issue
dta.co2.interpolate(inplace=True)

res = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(dta.co2)
res.plot()
```

[image: seasonal decomposition plot]

They say it is *naive* but there is no disclaimer about what is wrong with it. Does anyone know?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. I guess it's "naive" because it uses simple convolution and averages to separate out trend and seasonal structure, i.e. it's not a fancy algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, @user333700 , I wonder if R's `decompose` is also "naive" and if and when it is ever necessary to go fancy. Get the impression given that `.seasonal_decompose` worked on my data that it's probably all you typically need.

Comment: One possibility where it is most likely too "naive", i.e. doesn't capture the features of the data appropriately, is shifting seasonal patterns, for example because of a trend or break in the pattern. Sometimes those can also be removed by a box-cox or similar transformation. Seasonal adjustments for macro economic data (e.g. by X11) also take shifts in holidays and similar calendar effects into account.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I made some (aehm...naive) researches, and, [according to the reference](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html), it seems that StatsModels uses the classic moving average method to detect trends and apply seasonal decomposition (you can check more [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/6), specifically about [Moving Average](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/6/2) and [Classical Decomposition](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/6/3)).

However, other advanced seasonal decomposition techniques are available, such as [STL decomposition](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/6/5), which also has some [Python implementations](https://github.com/jrmontag/STLDecompose). (**UPDATE - 11/04/2019** as pointed out in the comments by @squarespiral, such implementations appear to have been merged in the master branch of StatsModels).

At the above links, you can find a complete reference on the advantages and disadvantages of each one of the proposed methods.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The "Python implementation" of STL decomposition is apparently already merged into statsmodels: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4044 - the documentation for the function is here: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/stl_decomposition.html

Comment: Thanks @squarespiral, I updated the answer according to your comment.

Comment: Great answer. Still, the +1 was mostly for the pun.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source codes](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.html#seasonal_decompose), `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal()` de-constructs a time series by:

1. **Trend** is computed by a convolutional window, decided by the argument `period=12`, for example;
2. The detrended time-series is obtained by either Raw-Trend or Raw/Trend, controlled by the argument `model`;
3. The **seasonal** is finally computed by averaging all temporal segments within a single period (e.g., 12 here);
4. Finally, the **residual** is the noise left.

I would say, it is somehow conventional and like a feature-engineering work for machine learning tasks. Not sure whether it will improve the performance for some advanced deep learning architectures (e.g. Transformer).